# css transform scale - overlaps on left but not right

Tags: html, css

Ok,

So I have a `<figure>` element that I want to scale using `transform: scale(1.2)` when on `:hover`.

It works fine except for one issue: the left overlaps fine, the right remains below the next element.

Here's the **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29axs/1/)**

As you can see, the left overlaps the previous element fine, the right "underlaps" the next element.

Here's the html

```
<section class="list-cover">
  <figure>
    <a href="" title="">
      <img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk0NDg4NjQ5N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzkzNTgyMTE@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg" alt="" />
      <figcaption>Caption Text</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="" title="">
      <img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAyMDM2ODExNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTI2MjkzMTE@._V1_SY317_CR9,0,214,317_AL_.jpg" alt="" />
      <figcaption>Caption Text</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="" title="">
      <img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIzMjgwMTQzMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDcyMjczMTE@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_AL_.jpg" alt="" />
      <figcaption>Caption Text</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="" title="">
      <img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg1MTIwODYwMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjAwNzQzMTE@._V1_SY317_CR2,0,214,317_AL_.jpg" alt="" />
      <figcaption>Caption Text</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="" title="">
      <img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTgzNjQ4NjM1NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzQ4OTEzNw@@._V1_SY317_CR11,0,214,317_AL_.jpg" alt="" />
      <figcaption>Caption Text</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
</section>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.list-cover figure {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .2em;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
  max-height: 315px;
  min-height: 315px;
}

.list-cover figure:hover,
.list-cover figure:active {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.list-cover figcaption {
  background: rgba(46, 204, 113, .7);
  margin-top: -30%;
  position: relative;
  padding: .5em;
  padding-top: 1.1em;
  transition: background-color .3s ease;
}

.list-cover figure:hover figcaption,
.list-cover figure:active figcaption {
  background-color: #ec008c;
}

.list-cover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Anyone have any idea how I can get the right side to overlap the next element?

Comment: Please use images that we can all see! PlaceKitten or LoremPizza are great services for this

Comment: Jsfiddle has been modified: http://jsfiddle.net/29axs/1/

Comment: -1 not enough http://lorempizza.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to increase the `z-index` of the `figure` being hovered. But in order for this to take effect, you also need to give it `position: relative` because z-index only works with non-static elements.

```
.list-cover figure {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
.list-cover figure:hover, .list-cover figure:active {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/29axs/2/)