# Image on hover overlaps image on the left but not on the right

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying scale up the size of an image on hover. The image is part of a gallery so there are other images on the left and right. The problem is the image on hover overlaps on the left image but not on the right.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747172/css-transform-scale-overlaps-on-left-but-not-right) question with the identical problem and tried the fix. It started working on firefox but still no change in Chrome. What's wrong here?

Html

```
<div class="row" id="attractions">
    <div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="attractions-title">
            <h1 class="text-center text-danger">Gallery</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <div class="gallery-item wow fadeIn hidden-xs" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                <img src="img/attractions/adventure-cove.jpg" alt="Adventure Cove Waterpark">
                <h4 class="text-center">Adventure Cove Waterpark</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-item wow fadeIn hidden-xs" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                <img src="img/attractions/gardens-by-the-bay-5.jpg" alt="Garden By The Bay">
                <h4 class="text-center">Garden By The Bay</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-item wow fadeIn hidden-xs" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                <img src="img/attractions/Marina-Bay-Sands-4.jpg" alt="Marina Bay Sands">
              <h4 class="text-center">Marina Bay Sands</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.gallery{
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
}

.gallery-item{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin: 15px auto 0px auto;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.gallery-item img{
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.gallery-item img:hover, .gallery-item img:active{
    transform: scale(1.4);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
    -o-transform: scale(1.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

You can see it in action [here](http://www.exploitrip.com/specialoffers/dubai-packages/)

Comment: What would you like to do? Would you like the image to overlap others or what?

Comment: When you use relative positioning, everything inside the element you give relative positioning is only positioned relative to what is inside that element. This applies to z-index also. So when you change the z-index of the image, it will only change relative to what is inside the containing element. Therefore it has no effect to some elements outside. You need to apply the hover and z-index to a higher level element. I.e. the `.gallery-item` and then you can do `.gallery-item:hover img` whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `z-index` solution to the .`gallery-item` element, instead of the images.

```css
.gallery{
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
}

.gallery-item{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin: 15px auto 0px auto;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    z-index: 9;
}

.gallery-item:hover, .gallery-item:active{
    z-index: 10;
}

.gallery-item img{
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.gallery-item img:hover, .gallery-item img:active{
    transform: scale(1.4);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
    -o-transform: scale(1.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
}
```